# Replacing words with specified words using AWK

Tags: bash, awk, text-editing

My code generates several json file all of which look similar to

```
{
    "instance": "sample_instance_05",
    "steps": [
        {
            "129": "North",
            "14": "North",
            "82": "North",
            "53": "North",
            "149": "North",
            "6": "North",
            "79": "North",
            "40": "North",
            "151": "North",
```

These files are all inside a single directory. My boss just told me that I should have generated the data with `N` for `North`, `S` for `South`, `E` for `East` and `W` for `West`.

Since these data files took quite some time to generate, I don't want to rerun the code again for such a simple text-replacement. AWK/SED/GREP etc.  are clearly the took for the job (I have used a bit of AWK before, but I am quite rusty)

Is there a simpler Bash + AWK loop, which allows me to transform all the lines in the file as indicated?

Answer (score 0):

#### `sed` method

I suggest using `sed`. The following should work to replace all instances of `word_1` to `word_2` in `myfile.json`.

```
$ sed -i 's/word_1/word_2/g' myfile.json
```

For example, to change "North" to "N":

```
$ sed -i 's/North/N/g' myfile.json
```

Note that the `-i` flag will invoke in-place editing and as such data will immediately be changed.

#### `awk` method

You can also use `awk` as such:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/word_1/,"word_2")}1' myfile.json > patchedfile.json
```